# Why does cUrl fail to download via HTTPS unless CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to "false"?

Tags: php, curl, azure, https

In my PHP code I try to download a file from a URL starting with `https://`

```
$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
curl_close($curlHandle);
```

`$response` happens to be `FALSE` unless I do this:

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before `curl_exec()` call.

The URL I download from is from Window Azure Blob Storage and starts with `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net` so I assume there should be no problems with the server SSL certificate.

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you have not configured curl with CA certificates that are considered trustworthy, so it has no way of verifying the signature on the remote server's certificate (although in all likelihood the signature is valid).

To verify the signature you should set either `CURLOPT_CAINFO` or `CURLOPT_CAPATH` appropriately.

Comment: something the browser takes care of when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Microsoft released an [SDK for PHP](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php) which would handle all these stuff for you and let your code be more about interacting with azure services instead of working with HTTP.